# Calculation on formatted price

Tags: laravel

i have a code a project for workshop....in inventory i added products with their prices and i formatted them using `$product->price = number_format($request->price, 2, ".", ",");` ...now in purchase order i multiply price with quantity ....remember my price is like 20,000.00 now when i load price to purchase order and multply by quantity i get an error (NaN) error

is there a way to convert back the number format to numeric or what method should i use to calculate formatted number

```
price = Input::get('price');
        $total_price = $qty * $price;  
        echo $total_price;
```

help please

Comment: has $qty been defined before?

Comment: what is the output of dd(Input::get('price'));

Comment: i didnt define the output of ```input::get ('price')``` sijadefine plus i dont use ```dd(Input::get('price'))``` @DeepeshThapa

Comment: We assume in a half decent attemp at self debugging you would of at least investigated the dd() of the input:price. Results could help resolve the issue much faster. I would suggest using bcmath library for your calculations. Precision is guaranteed and the error would be very obvious.